# discord.js upper case & lower case embed message not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I wrote a "test" command and wanted to make it in a way where when people type -test, the upper cases and lower cases don't matter. The command should work with -test, -Test, -TEST, etc. Currently, the command only works with -test and no upper cases. I also tried changing it from `toLowerCase();` to `toUpperCase();` and the `(command === 'test')` to `(command === 'TEST')` but it didn't help. Only the -test command with no upper cases worked.

Here's my code:

```
client.on('message', message =>{

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'test') || message.author.bot) return;

    var pfpMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split('  ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'test'){

        const testEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#6567AD')
            .setTitle('Some title')
            .setAuthor(pfpMember.user.username, pfpMember.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setDescription('Some description here')
            .setThumbnail(pfpMember.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .addField('something', 'Some value here')
            .addField('something', 'Some value here', true)
            .addField('something', 'Some value here', true)
            .addField('something', 'Some value here', true)
            .setImage(pfpMember.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setFooter('Some footer text here', pfpMember.user.displayAvatarURL());

        message.channel.send(testEmbed);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your command to be case insensitive, you should coerce the user input to one case (lowercase). You've already done that with `const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()`. However, at the beginning of your code you stick an unnecessary and inhibiting

```js
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'test') || message.author.bot) return;
```

Remove that "+ 'test'".

Also don't split by two spaces, you could probably split by a whitespace regular expression:

Your polished code should now be

```js
client.on('message', message =>{

     if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    var pfpMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'test'){

        const testEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#6567AD')
            .setTitle('Some title')
            .setAuthor(pfpMember.user.username, pfpMember.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setDescription('Some description here')
            .setThumbnail(pfpMember.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .addField('something', 'Some value here')
            .addField('something', 'Some value here', true)
            .addField('something', 'Some value here', true)
            .addField('something', 'Some value here', true)
            .setImage(pfpMember.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setFooter('Some footer text here', pfpMember.user.displayAvatarURL());

        message.channel.send(testEmbed);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your changes dont matter because you are checking if `message.content === prefix+'test'`. Using the `+'test'` makes the bot only accept lowercase `'test'`.
Instead you should use the following:

```js
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
```

and spilt by 1 space instead of two, `.spilt(' ')` and you should be good to go!